# Python Regex Zipcode Matching

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex that matches zipcodes in northern California.  I'd like to get them into a single regex; is this possible?

```
(re.match(r'9[0-2].+', zip) or re.match(r'93[0-5].+', zip))
```

I've tried:

```
re.match(r'9[0-2|3[0-5].+', zip)
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Whenever you got some regex testing, just try stuff with an online regex tester like http://ksamuel.pythonanywhere.com/ Most of the time it's just about trying stuff for 20 minutes untill it works, then you realize why it worked. Plus try to avoid "." if you can be more specific, your regex will be faster and will catch less false positive. i'm pretty sure you don't have "$", "^" or "#" in a zip code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
re.match(r'9([0-2]|3[0-5]).+', zip)
```

Comment: Thanks, David, just came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Isnt' a problem with `.+` that a string like '900' will match?

Comment: @ZacharyYoung- absolutely, I was just trying to be faithful to scoopseven's original regexes.

Comment: That's correct, and it should. 90210-1282 is a valid zip, and should also match.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little puzzled as to why you're using a `.` in your regex. `.` matches any character, and as far as I know zip codes can only contain numbers.

I think you actually want `(9[0-2]\d{3}|93[0-5]\d\d)`.

**Edit**: Alternatively, `9([0-2]\d|3[0-5])\d\d` for a shorter regex.

Comment: What about the '-' that separates the two parts (where optional second part is given)?

Comment: He may be overgeneralizing to match ZIP+4 codes, which could contain a hyphen (92196-3942 as a made-up example)

Comment: @Marcin: You mean ZIP+4 syntax? You'd just add `(-\d{4})?` to the end.